# How to think of acceleration vectors

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, vectors, spacetime-dimensions

I understand:

- How average/instantaneous acceleration works for 1D-motion
- Velocity vectors

But I don't understand the concept of acceleration for 2D-motion. What does the vector subtraction $\Delta \vec{v} = \vec{ v_{a}} - \vec{ v_{b}}$ actually mean?

I hope I'm not being too vague. I can make the calculations but it feels uncomfortable doing them and not truly understanding.

Comment: I didn't understand where are you facing problems with acceleration or with vectors?

Comment: Are you familiar with vector addition?

Comment: What is your actual question: concept of acceleration or concept of vector arithmetic? And if you understand velocity vectors, do you realize that they involve vector subtraction: $\Delta\vec{x}=\vec{x}_a-\vec{x}_b$?

Comment: Acceleration Vector = Change in Velocity Vector per unit of time.

Answer (score 1):

Do the calculation with numbers you can grasp. Picture a person walking across a chessboard from one corner to another. They are walking at a 45 degree angle from the edges of the board. If you plot their movement along one side or the other you get a line up or to the side.

If you look at the person from the side of the chessboard and ignore that they are getting farther away you will see them moving to the right (horizontal axis) at a steady velocity. Lets say that is 2 miles per hour. If you look at them from the other side (vertical axis) you see them again moving at 2 miles per hour. But if you look at them from above you see that they are indeed moving faster than 2 mph. Using the Pythagorean theorem you see they are moving at about 2.8 mph.

What I did was to add the vectors together to get the net velocity and direction.

In class you will be given problems with many vectors to add to determine the ultimate direction and speed. They will get more complex, but just do them one step at a time and it will work out.

Drew K

Answer (score 1):

$\vec v_b$ is the initial velocity and $\vec v_a$ is the final velocity.
Change in velocity = final velocity - initial velocity $\;\Rightarrow\; \Delta \vec  v = \vec v_a +(-\vec v_b)$
This is shown below.

[image]

Another way of looking at the same situation is to write
final velocity = initial velocity + change in velocity $\;\Rightarrow\; \vec v_a = \vec v_b + \Delta \vec v$
This is shown in the right most vector diagram.